# correlation of pairs of features

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have $N$ subjects, $s_1,s_2,\dots,s_N$. I calculated the similarity of each pair of those subjects based on certain features which results in a similarity matrix, $S\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}, 0\le S_{ij}\le1, S_{ii}=0$. I also have the ages of the subjects, $a_1,\dots,a_n$. I want to test the hypothesis that if two subjects are very similar, then they are also in the same age group. More specifically, I am interested in finding the relationship between the most similar subjects per each row of the matrix $S$ (In other words, the subjects pair that gives the max similarity per each row) and their ages. Formally, let the set $D$ represents the pairs of subjects that have the highest similarity per each row, $D=\{(s_1,s_{k_1}),\dots,(s_N,s_{k_N})\},s_{k_1}\in\{2,\dots,N\}, ,s_{k_2}\in\{1,3,\dots,N\},\dots,s_{k_N}\in\{1,\dots,N-1\}$

Let the set $A$ be the corresponding age pairs of the set $D$, $A=\{(a_1,a_{k_1}),\dots,(a_N,a_{k_N})\}$. I would like to test the hypothesis if $d(s_1,s_{k_i}) \rightarrow 0$, then $d(a_1,a_{k_i})\rightarrow 0$, where $d$ is the distance.

Here is a thought but I think it is statistically not robust as it does not give a p-value for my hypothesis: I create another similarity matrix based on the ages $S^a\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}, 0\le S_{ij}^a\le1$. However, one caveat is that the similarity function that is used for ages is not the same as the similarity function used in calculating the similarity for the subjects' features. Nontheless, I vectorize the two similarity matrices and then calculate the cosine similarity

Comment: The different similarities ({s1,s2} vs {s1,s3} vs {s2,s3}) aren't all independent of each other, so the typical statistical test won't be valid.  A permutation test might work.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica you are right. However, I am only picking a one pair in each similarity matrix's row, which is the pair that gives the max similarity. So, my sample is indeed independent.

Comment: Hmm, yes, I see that now on rereading it.  "Most similar subjects" is post-hoc, though.  So you'd need to account for that.